# Button and Text In VStack

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to define the following View in SwiftUI but it is not working:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Placeholder")
        Button(action: {
            // Do something
        }) {
            Text("Button")
        }
    }
}
```

The error is :

```
Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type
```

There are also two warnings:

```
Result of 'Text' initializer is unused
```

and

```
Result of 'Button<Label>' initializer is unused
```

I am trying to code with XCode11 on Mac with OS Catalina. Does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add mentioned `VStack`

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {                // << here !!
       Text("Placeholder")
       Button(action: {
        // Do something
       }) {
          Text("Button")
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the `VStack` :

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Placeholder")
        Button("Button"){ }
    }
}
```